# What is the difference between HttpFactory and HttpJson?

Tags: angularjs

What is the different of HttpFactory and HttpJson?
For example,

```
HttpJson.json( CONST.method_put, CONST.reception_ankeninfo_url, param 
).then(function( strs ) 
    isInfo = $scope.input.notSubject ? true : false;
    isClShitei = strs.data.client_shitei_trader_umu_flg == '1' ? true : false;
    var lock = {};
    lock.login_id = login_id;
    lock.uketsuke_id = uketsuke_id;
    return HttpFactory.data( CONST.method_post, CONST.arrange_tehailock_url, lock, { ignoreError: true }
    ).then(function( strs ) {
        ArrangeTemporary.arrange_transaction_id = strs.data.transaction_id;
    });
});
```

Comment: Those two services are not part of the core services for the AngularJS framework. To help you, we need to see the code for those two services.

Comment: Seems like these services are implemented by your product development team itself & are not part of angular core libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like these services are implemented by your product development
>   team itself & are not part of angular core libraries.

The major difference as name suggests, `HttpJSON` is targeted to make http requests with `content-type` as `application/json`

while,

HttpFactory will return an object which can be used to make generic http requests where you can set `content-type` & other `headers` as per your requirement.